# Is it possible to share an existing asp.net applications membership database with sharepoint 2010's, when using Forms based authentication

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, membership, fba

I am trying to integrate an existing asp.net application with sharepoint 2010. I would like to be able to have a logged in user on the application access a document library via an Iframe on the sharepoint 2010 site. I want to use FBA on sharepoint. Is it possible to share the membership database from the asp.net application with sharepoint? If not, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The databases are identical so there is no reason you can't point the SharePoint FBA connection string to your existing database. However, I doubt the user will be transparently logged in.