# Is it possible to share an existing asp.net applications identity database with sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-identity

It is currently possible to share a membership database between sharepoint 2010 and an asp.net application.

[Is it possible to share an existing asp.net applications membership database with sharepoint 2010's, when using Forms based authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207255/is-it-possible-to-share-an-existing-asp-net-applications-membership-database-wit)

Can I share an asp.net identity database with sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, obviously I wasn't focused enough while reading your question.
I didn't try it myself but ACS with custom identity provider may help you:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22309.integrating-windows-live-id-google-and-facebook-accounts-with-sharepoint-2013-white-paper.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2012/11/02/azure-access-control-services-creating-a-custom-identity-provider.aspx

Answer (score 1):

yes you can.
check this post: http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2013/09/20/configuring-sharepoint-2013-forms-based-authentication-with-sqlmembershipprovider.aspx
nothing changed in SP 2013

Comment: SqlMembership membership provider is significantly different to ASP.NET Identity membership provider.  The link you refer to only mentions SqlMembership and not ASP.NET Identity so unfortunately this doesn't answer my question (but thanks anyway)